# Access file system through query string or params

Tags: asp.net, security, request.querystring, http-request-parameters

I have been given a task of reproducing the issue/testing the unauthorized access to file system through request.param and query string.

For instance i have something like this. request.querystring("blah"); 
How could somebody pass "../../../b1/b2" in the query string and access file system.

This may be related to cross site scripting.

Need help..at least provide resources. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking of how to hack using Remote File Inclusion (RFI), Local File Inclusion (LFI)?

Comment: @ K Lvanov, Well i am asking for how to do cross site scripting. In order to induce in the request parameters and access the file system. like the following.  <img src="getimage.aspx?img=../../somefile.txt". I am not sure what is RFI and LFIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish I could provide a definitive answer, but can at least steer you in *some* direction.  Not sure how confident you are that request.querystring() was indeed responsible, but some possibilities are:

**Directory Traversal/Path Traversal:**

Overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal
Testing For: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Path_Traversal

**Remote File Inclusion:**

Overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion
Tutorial: http://www.offensivecomputing.net/?q=node/624 (KnightLighter's Tutorial)

Hope this moves you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the links which helped me understanding. Can you provide info of how to implement the attack. I want to attack my own site and see the whether it is preventing it or not.

Comment: requesting the page with ?<script>alert("hi")</script> throwing the potentially dangerous request exception. How to perform testing even if the validateRequest is true. Basically how to by pass and perform injection.

Comment: @gtk The link to owasp has a section on testing for the exploit. Might also check out metasploit if you intend to conduct pen testing.  Roll up your sleeves and good luck ;)